# What is the probability that $m$ items drawn from $n$ distinct items contain all $n$ items?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

Suppose there are $n$ distinct items to be drawn with replacement for $m$ times, the probability of each item being drawn is assumed to be $\frac{1}{n}$. What is the probability $P(m)$ that $m$ items drawn from the $n$ items contain all $n$ items?

Apparently, if $m<n$

$$P(m)=0$$

For $m=n$,

$$P(m)=P(n)=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

For $m>n$, I have no idea how to formulate the nominator.

$$P(m)=\frac{?}{n^m}$$

Comment: For $m>n$ I would rephrase it like the probability that no item gets drawn zero times, since you are allowed redraws of the same item.

Comment: @M.Nestor yep, it's a good problem transformation, do you have some clues about the formulation of the probability of the event "no items get drawn 0 time"?

Answer (score 1):

A lower bound can come from assessing the chance that a particular item has not been seen.  On each draw you have $1-\frac 1n$ chance of not getting it, so on $m$ draws you have $(1-\frac 1n)^m$ chance of never seeing it.  The chance you have not seen some item is then less than $n(1-\frac 1n)^m$.  This is the expected number not to see.  The chance of having not seen at least one is less than this because sometimes you will have missed more than one, but if the chance of missing one is small the chance of missing two is very small.  We can use the fact that $(1-\frac 1n)^n \approx e^{-1}$ to write the expected number to miss as $$n\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^m=n\left(\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n\right)^{\frac mn}\approx n\left(e^{-1}\right)^{\frac mn}=ne^{-\frac mn}$$
and the chance of missing at least one is less than this.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is $$n! \, S_2(m,n)$$ where $S_2(m,n)$ represents a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), sometimes written ${m\brace n}$.  There is no simple closed form for these, but there are a relatively simple recurrence, generating function and inclusion-exclusion alternating sum of combinations

For example if we call this $f(m,n)=n! \, S_2(m,n)$ then we get

$$S_2(m,n) = S_2(m-1,n-1)+n\,S_2(m-1,n) \\f(m,n) = n(f(m-1,n-1)+f(m-1,n))$$

both starting with $S_2(0,0)=f(0,0)=1$ and $S_2(0,n)=f(0,n)=0$ for $n \not = 0$

For small $m$ and $n$, the values of $f(m,n)=n! \, S_2(m,n)$ are

```
   n: 1    2    3    4    5
m
1     1    0    0    0    0
2     1    2    0    0    0
3     1    6    6    0    0
4     1   14   36   24    0
5     1   30  150  240  120
```

and it should be fairly clear that $150=3(14+36)$ and similar patterns with the other entries

Comment: My understanding is that you first calculated the number of ways to split $m$ draws into $n$ partitions ($S_2(m,n)$), and then permutated the $n$ items to place ($n!$) in the $n$ partitions. Therefore, the total number is $n!S_2(m,n)$. I had a similar idea but my result for the number of ways to split is $C_{m-1}^{n-1}$, i.e., the number of ways to place $n-1$ bars into $m-1$ bins ([Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)))... (1/2)

Comment: ... I know it's incorrect, since $n!C_{m-1}^{n-1}$ would count some permutations twice. Therefore, I was wondering what the difference is between $C_{m-1}^{n-1}$ and $S_2(m,n)$? and how the Stirling number prevents itself from repeated counts? (2/2)

Comment: @GuoyangQin: to me personally, $n!S_2(m,n)$ is a more useful number than $S_2(m,n)$ on its own, since $S_2(m,n)$ is for distinguishable balls into indistinguishable boxes each getting at least one ball.  The $n!$ comes from considering which is the first box to receive a ball ($n$ possibilities), then the second box to receive a ball ($n-1$ possibilities), and so on, i.e. making the boxes distinguishable. *Stars and bars* would be equivalent to counting indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes, and there would not be a simple translation to distinguishable balls....

Comment: @GuoyangQin: ...  In your question, you have distinguishable draws (corresponding to the balls) and distinguishable items (corresponding to the boxes).

Comment: @GuoyangQin My $f(m,n) = n(f(m-1,n-1)+f(m-1,n))$ comes from saying that with the $m$th draw either all $n$ items have already been drawn in $f(m-1,n)$ ways  so you can draw any of them this time giving $n$ possibilities, or all-except-one items have already been drawn so $n$ possibilities for the item not previously drawn and the other items have been drawn in $f(m-1,n-1)$ ways with you now needing to draw the missing item